# Read HTML from Arduino using PHP

Tags: php, curl, arduino

I am very new here and have no experience with PHP and just need this one application to work. I think I am pretty close, but for some reason it doesnt work.

In my setup, I use an Arduino Uno eith the Ethernet Shield 2 to host a basic HTML website that just displays some text based on the input on 5 pins. That part works just fine, but now I want to read this text and include it on a website Im working on. After some googling I thought that it could be done with a simple PHP script, but it doesnt work with the Arduino, I dont get an error message, it just doesnt work.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80);

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //while (!Serial) {
    //; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  //}


  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
while (client.connected()) {
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
    // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
    // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
    // so you can send a reply
    if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
      // send a standard http response header
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
      //client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
      client.println("Refresh: 30");  // refresh the page automatically every X sec
      client.println();
      client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
      client.println("<html>");
      // output the value of each analog input pin
      for (int analogChannel = 0; analogChannel < 6; analogChannel++) {
        int sensorReading = analogRead(analogChannel);
        if(sensorReading>1000){
        client.print("Toilet ");
        client.print(analogChannel);
        client.print(" is occupied.");
        client.print("<br />");
        }
        else{
        client.print("Toilet ");
        client.print(analogChannel);
        client.print(" is free.");
        client.print("<br />");
        }
      }
      client.println("</html>");
      break;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
      // you're starting a new line
      currentLineIsBlank = true;
    }
    else if (c != '\r') {
      // you've gotten a character on the current line
      currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
echo get_data('http://192.168.1.177/');
?>
```

I am fully aware that there are much more elegant and more effective solutions for what I am trying to achieve, but in this case, I really just need this to work, it doesnt have to be perfect!
My guess is that I have to configure the Arduino in some way to allow this connection, but I dont know enough about this...

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is your script inside the same network as your arduino?

Comment: Yes, sorry should have specified that... I can connect, the script just doesnt work.

Comment: Before the line: `curl_close($ch);`, paste this line and comment the output `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));`

Comment: Array ( [url] => http://192.168.1.177/ [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 4.205097 [namelookup_time] => 0.00026 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 [redirect_url] => )

Comment: The php is OK, but it fails connecting to your Arduino and returns http code 0. So the problem must be there, sorry I can't help.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought too... Thanks anyway, appreciate you taking the time! :)